# Working with AccessibilityNodeInfo caused stack size 8MB error

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I used accessibility service to get all texts on screen. After minutes working normally, it caused ANR with some `GC allocated...` logs and few seconds after, it crashed with this error:
[image]

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {
    try {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (powerManager == null || !powerManager.isInteractive()) {
            return;
        }
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) return;
        CharSequence eventPackageName = event.getPackageName();
        if (eventPackageName != null) {
            if (eventPackageName.equals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)) return;
            if (eventPackageName.equals(getCurrentKeyboardPackageName())) return;
            int eventType = event.getEventType();
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED || eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo mNodeInfo = event.getSource();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
                    getAllTextViews(mNodeInfo, stringBuilder);
                    String value = stringBuilder.toString().replace('\n', ' ').replaceAll(" +", " ");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My `getAllTextViews()` method:

```
private void getAllTextViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        if (nodeInfo == null) return;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nodeInfo.getText())) {
            stringBuilder.append(" " + nodeInfo.getText());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
            getAllTextViews(nodeInfo.getChild(i), stringBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank a lot!

Comment: You're hitting an infinite loop inside `getAllTextViews`, although I can't immediately tell where. Try outputting the contents of `stringBuilder` before each call to `getAllTextViews`, you should see where it's getting stuck.

Comment: @JakeSteam hi. It's not an infinite loop because i put `nodeInfo == null` check inside. And I also get result. Just some cases it randomly throw that error.

Comment: In that case, sounds like sometimes there's just too many textviews for the stack to handle. I suggest either setting a max level to explore down to, or using multiple stacks. If you could add an example situation that causes the issue to your question somehow, it would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use `recycle()` method of `AccessibilityNodeInfo` after info is used.